# Why can't I set a resolution of 2560*1600 on my Dell Latitude e6320?

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

I have:

- a 30" Apple cinema display, native resolution 2560*1600
- a Dell Latitude e6320
- an ePort+ docking station
- a displayport to dual-link DVI-D adaptor

The display has a dual-link DVI-D lead fused to the case.

The laptop has:

- intel HD 3000 graphics (known to support this resolution)
- a built in VGA port (useless)
- a built in mini-HDMI port (introduced with HDMI 1.3, and therefore capable of driving WQXGA?)
- Windows 7 32-bit
- The latest BIOS (A15)
- The latest graphics drivers from Dell

The docking station has:

- Two dual-link DVI-D ports
- Two displayport ports

I've tried both DVI ports and the both displayport ports with the adaptor and the best Windows will offer is 1280*800.

Hitting "list all modes" under graphics properties shows up to 1920*1080, but selecting it turns the display black until windows reverts to 1280*800.

The Intel graphics and media control panel has a custom resolution pane that lets you type in whatever you want. Inputting 2560*1600 gets you a "the custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity" unless you dial it down to 30Hz... which just gives a black display again.

Current theories are that despite offering Dual Link DVI ports the docking station doesn't actually wire them up as such... is that a thing that happens? The same would also go for the displayport-DVI dongle I have, mind, which seems improbable.

One avenue is looking for a mini-HDMI to DVI-D adaptor, though a brief search suggests these are rare and expensive.

On paper this should just work ;_;

Comment: Have you verified your DVI cable is indeed dual link capable? Check the pins - see [Wikipedia: DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector).

Comment: I have - the pins on the DVI ports on the docking station, the displayport dongle, and the cable fused to the monitor are all consistent with dual-link DVI. My suspicion is that Dell have wired up dual-link ports as single-link in order to keep some part of their process similar.

Comment: Also consider that Dell might wire up dual-link ports as single-link not to save money (I for one don't believe that would be any cheaper), but in order to segment the market and force you to buy a more expensive model (with the same chipset) in order to get the full functionality of the chipset you anyway have. Segmentation isn't the root of all evil, but it's at the root of much evil...

Answer (score 1):

A few minutes worth of searching turned up this post. Apparently you need to use DisplayPort in order to achieve the resolution you desire.

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/10054/solved-whats-the-max-resoulion-supported-on-intel-hd-3000/

Comment: A few seconds worth of searching turned up [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVI#Connector). Apparently DVI *does* support that resolution if it is dual-link.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I ordered an expensive active displayport-DVI adaptor off eBay and it works perfectly from the docking station's displayport.

I guess the apparent dual-link DVI ports on the Dell docking station and the Dell displayport dongle were both bogus. Despite having all the pins, they were wired up as single-link DVI ports.

Dell is terrible, is the take-away here.

Comment: Contact them. Was there any mention of this in the manuals? If not, then you can file a complaint about a defective part because essentially, that *is* defective. Maybe they simply didn’t realize what they were doing and will send you a replacement or something. If they did in fact do it on purpose, then don’t fill in the blanks for yourself, force *them* to say it out loud in no uncertain terms that they purposely limited it so that you would have to pay more money. That way you can hold them accountable (e.g., a potential class-action suit) instead of just quietly assuming and moving on.